# Unable to Insert with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've tried a few different things and I am getting a few different errors. I'm trying to use Entity Framework and am doing code-first development. I'm currently getting the error

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.

I know this isn't possible though as I am just running this locally on my own machine. I think that is has something to do with my PK, but I am not sure.

I have tried a few different things, but no luck.

Here is my code:

`User.cs` - this is my model

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string AspNetUserId { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in my controller I am trying to insert a new user:

```
Model.Models.User.User usr = new Model.Models.User.User()
{
    AspNetUserId = user.Id.ToString()
};
userService.CreateUser(usr);
userService.SaveUser();
```

Here is my `UserService.cs`:

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    private readonly IUserRepository usersRepository;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;

    public UserService(IUserRepository usersRepository, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        this.usersRepository = usersRepository;
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers()
    {
        var users = usersRepository.GetAll();
        return users;
    }

    public User GetUser(int id)
    {
        var user = usersRepository.GetById(id);
        return user;
    }

    public User Get(string aspNetUserId)
    {
        Expression<Func<User, bool>> exp = c => c.AspNetUserId == aspNetUserId;
        var user = usersRepository.Get(exp);
        return user;
    }

    public void CreateUser(User user)
    {
        usersRepository.Add(user);
    }

    public void SaveUser()
    {
        unitOfWork.Commit();
    }
}
```

I tried a few different things, including removing `[Key]` from the `ID` field in `User.cs`, changing to `DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None`.. still nothing.

My database is set up correctly and the `ID` column in my `Users` table is the primary key and an auto-increment identity. If I just insert a row in SSMS, it works.

Any ideas? Let me know if you need to see more code.

---- EDIT

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly IDbFactory dbFactory;
    private CollegeBaseballManagerEntities dbContext;

    public UnitOfWork(IDbFactory dbFactory)
    {
        this.dbFactory = dbFactory;
    }

    public CollegeBaseballManagerEntities DbContext
    {
        get
        {
            if (dbContext == null)
                return dbContext = dbFactory.Init();
            else
                return dbContext;
        }
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        DbContext.Commit();
    }
}

public class CollegeBaseballManagerEntities : DbContext
{
    public CollegeBaseballManagerEntities() : base("CollegeBaseballManagerEntities") { }

    public DbSet<League> Leagues { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    public virtual void Commit()
    {
        base.SaveChanges();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<CollegeBaseballManagerEntities>(null);
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new LeagueConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserConfigurations());
    }
}
```

-- SECOND EDIT

Got it! My `UserRepository.Add()` looks like:

```
public virtual void Add(T entity)
{
    dbSet.Attach(entity);
    dataContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

I changed it to, and it worked.

```
public virtual void Add(T entity)
{
    dbSet.Attach(entity);
    dataContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
}
```

Comment: Added a couple of more classes.

Comment: What is the definition of `UserRepository.Add()`?

Comment: Thanks... you led me to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody else running into this issue, make sure you are setting the state of the entity to `Added`, not `Modified`.

```
dataContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
```

This solved my issue.